# in Twiiter Bootstrap when I minimize my window my carousel loses width and height to even out which is good but then it leaves a huge gap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, margin

Ok so I have a simple carousel

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide"> 
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
          <img src="img/Kids.jpg" alt="">
          <div class="container">

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="../assets/img/examples/slide-02.jpg" alt="">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>Another example headline.</h1>
              <p class="lead">Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
              <a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="#">Learn more</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="../assets/img/examples/slide-03.jpg" alt="">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>One more for good measure.</h1>
              <p class="lead">Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
              <a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="#">Browse gallery</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
    </div><!-- /.carousel -->
```

with some css to make it responsive so that it wont distort the image

```
.container-fluid{ 
                    padding:0px;
                  margin:0px;
                  }
    .carousel {
      margin-bottom: 60px;
      margin-top:-16px;
    }

    body{
                  padding:0px;
                  margin:0px;
                 }

    .carousel .container {
      position: relative;
      z-index: 9;
      width:100%;
    }

    .carousel-control {
      height: 80px;
      margin-top: 0;
      font-size: 120px;
      text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
      background-color: transparent;
      border: 0;
      z-index: 10;
    }

    .carousel .item {
    height:550px;
    }
    .carousel img {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height:auto;
    }

    @media (max-width: 979px) {

        body{
                  padding:0px;
                  margin:0px;
                 }

      .carousel .item {
        height: 350px;
      }
      .carousel img {
        width: 100%;
        height:auto;
      }

    }


    @media (max-width: 767px) {

              body{
                  padding:0px;
                  margin:0px;
                 }

      .carousel {
        margin-left: -20px;
        margin-right: -20px;
      }
      .carousel .container {

      }
      .carousel .item {
        height: 350px;

      }
      .carousel img {
        width: 100%;
        height:auto;
      }
    @media (max-width: 470px) {
    .carousel img {
        width: 100%;
        height:auto;
      }
    }
```

now I did the width 100% and height auto so as I minimize the screen the image will also lose width and height so that it wont distort the image but when I do that all the content I have underneath the carousel STAYS IN PLACE creating a a huge gap in between the carousel and the content below it. I just have 3 paragraphs lined up in span 4 underneath the carousel nothing really special. iv been trying to find out why it's been doing this for a while now and I came sort of close. the **.carousel item {}** stays in place while the **.carousel img{}** decreases. so in other words I put that **.carousel item {}** has 550px of height which is where I think I messed up even tho thats the height of the image, so I attempted in  putting height auto or max-height:550px but that only made the entire image in the caorusel disappear. It's like the content below the carousel isn't acting responsive and im not sure why. I have all the twitter bootstrap assets linked and what not.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use this CSS:

```
.carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
    display: block;
    height:auto;  
    max-width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    line-height: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem.

After 3 days of torment, I realised that simply removing the height statements from the carousel item did the trick. Just delete any reference to height!

Live example of the fix: http://s91288.gridserver.com/port/index_test.html

Comment: Okay Stewbob, thanks. I thought it might be okay since I'm having the same problem as the original question and it wasn't answered. :)
As it happens, I've just fixed it. I'll leave a proper answer below!